# Upward continuous multiplication?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

While reading the preface of Terence Tao's An *Introduction to Measure Theory*, I came across the following statement:

> We note also that once one adopts the convention $+\infty\cdot0 =
> 0\cdot+\infty= 0$, then multiplication becomes upward continuous (in the
> sense that whenever $x_n \in [0, +\infty]$ increases to $x \in [0, +\infty]$, and $y_n \in [0, +\infty]$ increases to $y \in [0, +\infty]$, then $x_ny_n$ increases to $xy$) but not downward continuous (*e.g.* $1/n \to 0$, but $1/n \cdot +\infty \not\to 0\cdot+\infty$).

Can anyone give me some intuition as to what this means? What would be an example of an upward continuous function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What he is calling "upward continuous" is (I believe) more commonly called "continuous from below". A function $f$ is continuous from below at $a$ if $$\lim_{x \to a-} f(x) = f(a)$$
An simple example is $$f(x) = \begin{cases}0 & x \le 0\\1 & x > 0\end{cases}$$
This function is continuous from below at $0$, but not from above. If changed it to have $f(0) =1$, then it would be continuous from above, but not from below.

Of course having two variables introduces a few more details, but they are straightforward once you understand the idea.

One thing to note is that Tao is only talking about continuity on $[0, \infty]$. If you consider negatives, then multiplication ceases to be continuous from below at $\langle 0, \infty \rangle$ either.